# Does the Catholic Church accept baptisms of other denominations?

Tags: catholicism, baptism

Is baptism from different denominations valid in Catholic Church? To my knowledge, anyone can baptise someone to the point of death of an unbaptised child/baby and adult.

Comment: I believe the duplicate answers your question.

Comment: @KenGraham Nothing in this question is about rebaptism...

Comment: @kris  and curiousdannii The highest voted one has the information desired in this question.

Comment: Kaylee there are a number of similar questions on the site. Catholics accept most other denominations baptisms as valid but not a Jesus name only baptism. And not a baptism in a non trinitarian church.

Comment: You will find your answer here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/203/do-any-major-denominations-refuse-to-recognize-holy-baptism-in-other-denominatio/16231#16231

Comment: Ok guys, thank you very much. I thought so coz not all denomination profess the faith of the Holy Trinity.

Comment: @KenGraham The answer may contain stuff relevant to this question, but the questions themselves are substantially different. We close questions as duplicates based on the text of the questions, not their answers. This question should be reopened because it does not ask about rebaptism in any way.